# Running https not on 443 how is this possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

If I hit my domain on any other port other than 443 I get the error below. How is it possible then to use nodejs https on different port?

**Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to mysite:8080. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)**

For example, in the example given in the documentation they use port 8000.

```
// curl -k https://localhost:8000/
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Using CentOS 6.

Comment: Your code is listening on port 8000, but the error you mentioned has port 8080.  Was that a typo?

Comment: No I am listening on 8080, the example from the documentation is using 8000. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I am using node express js using express sub domain set a domain for html page but issue is when page load its inner script are loaded with https but browser url still http

Answer (score 10, accepted):

record_too_long often/usually means you sent non-SSL-data to a client expecting SSL.

Try to visit your site and port via HTTP (not HTTPS). If it works, you have accidentally bound an HTTP server to it, not an HTTPS server.

Comment: Amazing thank you. I still don't know how I've managed to bind a http server as I'm using the https include yet you've put me on the right path. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

At this very moment I have a Node.js server running on port 3000 using HTTPS.

`SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` seems to indicate that there's a problem with the hostname ([Source](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2012-05/0068.html))

The error you've included mentions **mysite:8080** which tells me that you're trying to connect to `mysite:8080` and that that address doesn't exist.

To debug this, try accessing the URL through a browser or by setting up a regular `HTTP` and see whether it's accessible.

Comment: It works fine over http. And that's the error I get when I hit the page directly. So I may have a SSL problem. I'm also using Cloudflare are you using this service? This could be causing me issue now.

Comment: @Iglo Just to clarify: I'm talking about running it over HTTP at port `8080` (and not just port `80`), does that work? My server is setup locally so I don't have to worry about firewalls or CDNs :)

Comment: yeah it works fine over http on port 8080, I can't run it in port 80 as I have a web server running on that port.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be Cloudflare that is causing me the problem. The SSL cert I've included is the servers and the request comes in from Cloudflare. Would that not be a problem?

Comment: @Iglo Yes, indeed. You should *definitely* look into that.