# NodeJS HTTPS server serving over HTTP instead of HTTPS when running inside Docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, next.js, https

I'm creating a website using NextJS and Docker so that I can easily deploy it. I used `npx-create-next-app` to initialize it and used [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) (slightly modified) to containerize it. Since I wanted to use SSL with my server without going through the hassle of setting up a proxy, I followed [this article](https://noobgrammer.com/2021/03/07/enable-https-in-local-nextjs-application/), and setup the custom server.

This worked fine when I ran it outside of a docker container, and performed as expected, serving over HTTPS. However when I containerized it, and tried to open the webpage over HTTPS, I came up with `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`, but I could open the page using just HTTP (which I could not do when running outside of a container). Some googling led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576362/running-https-not-on-443-how-is-this-possible), from which I concluded that when running outside of a docker container, the custom server runs the server over HTTPS, as expected, however when I containerize it, it starts running HTTP, even though no code has been changed.

I'd expect the behavior to be the same when running locally or containerized.

At first I assumed this was due to invalid `key` and `cert` values in `httpsOptions` however I wasn't able to find anything that would make them invalid, and I don't see how that would cause this strange behavior. I tried changing the Docker run environment from `node:alpine-16` to just `node:latest` to see if it had something to do with the parent image, but that was fruitless.

One other minor issue I had is that `console.log` does not seem to output to the container's log for some reason, I tried googling this but didn't find much of anything pertaining to it. This has made debugging much harder as I can't really output any debug data. The only log I get when running inside of a container is `Listening on port 3000 url: http://localhost:3000`, which I assume is output by some library/package as it isn't anywhere in my code.

Here is my custom server code in case it would be helpful:

```js
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/fullchain.pem')
};


app.prepare().then(() => {
    https.createServer(httpsOptions, async (req, res) => { // When running on docker this creates an HTTP server instead of HTTPS
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
        const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`Ready on https://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Link to a reproducible example [here](https://github.com/jaydevelopsstuff/Docker-HTTPS-Bug-MRE).

Comment: Please include Dockerfile and also your code that you have, so basically a minimal reproducible solution.

Comment: @zsolt I can't include the code and Dockerfile as this is proprietary and going to be used in production, but I'll try to create a reproducible sample and post it as soon as I can.

Comment: Yes, only a minimal sample is needded, that can reproduce the same error/problem. For the code only this server creation is needed and running node in Dockerfile is pretty generic. Best would be if you uploaded this sample project to github.

Comment: @zsolt here, I posted it on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/jaydevelopsstuff/Docker-HTTPS-Bug-MRE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, based on your [sample repo](https://github.com/jaydevelopsstuff/Docker-HTTPS-Bug-MRE), that your server.js file that is in the root of your repo gets overwritten in the image because of this line in the Dockerfile:

`COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./`

So the actual server.js that is running in the container is the server.js that is created by the `yarn build` command and it looks like this (you can exec into the container and see it for yourself):

```
const NextServer = require('next/dist/server/next-server').default
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
process.chdir(__dirname)

// Make sure commands gracefully respect termination signals (e.g. from Docker)
// Allow the graceful termination to be manually configurable
if (!process.env.NEXT_MANUAL_SIG_HANDLE) {
  process.on('SIGTERM', () => process.exit(0))
  process.on('SIGINT', () => process.exit(0))
}

let handler

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await handler(req, res)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.statusCode = 500
    res.end('internal server error')
  }
})
const currentPort = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000

server.listen(currentPort, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Failed to start server", err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  const nextServer = new NextServer({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: currentPort,
    dir: path.join(__dirname),
    dev: false,
    customServer: false,
    conf: {"env":{},"webpack":null,"webpackDevMiddleware":null,"eslint":{"ignoreDuringBuilds":false},"typescript":{"ignoreBuildErrors":false,"tsconfigPath":"tsconfig.json"},"distDir":"./.next","cleanDistDir":true,"assetPrefix":"","configOrigin":"next.config.js","useFileSystemPublicRoutes":true,"generateEtags":true,"pageExtensions":["tsx","ts","jsx","js"],"target":"server","poweredByHeader":true,"compress":true,"analyticsId":"","images":{"deviceSizes":[640,750,828,1080,1200,1920,2048,3840],"imageSizes":[16,32,48,64,96,128,256,384],"path":"/_next/image","loader":"default","loaderFile":"","domains":[],"disableStaticImages":false,"minimumCacheTTL":60,"formats":["image/webp"],"dangerouslyAllowSVG":false,"contentSecurityPolicy":"script-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; sandbox;","remotePatterns":[],"unoptimized":false},"devIndicators":{"buildActivity":true,"buildActivityPosition":"bottom-right"},"onDemandEntries":{"maxInactiveAge":15000,"pagesBufferLength":2},"amp":{"canonicalBase":""},"basePath":"","sassOptions":{},"trailingSlash":false,"i18n":{"locales":["en"],"defaultLocale":"en"},"productionBrowserSourceMaps":false,"optimizeFonts":true,"excludeDefaultMomentLocales":true,"serverRuntimeConfig":{},"publicRuntimeConfig":{},"reactStrictMode":true,"httpAgentOptions":{"keepAlive":true},"outputFileTracing":true,"staticPageGenerationTimeout":60,"swcMinify":true,"output":"standalone","experimental":{"middlewarePrefetch":"flexible","optimisticClientCache":true,"manualClientBasePath":false,"legacyBrowsers":false,"newNextLinkBehavior":true,"cpus":7,"sharedPool":true,"profiling":false,"isrFlushToDisk":true,"workerThreads":false,"pageEnv":false,"optimizeCss":false,"nextScriptWorkers":false,"scrollRestoration":false,"externalDir":false,"disableOptimizedLoading":false,"gzipSize":true,"swcFileReading":true,"craCompat":false,"esmExternals":true,"appDir":false,"isrMemoryCacheSize":52428800,"fullySpecified":false,"outputFileTracingRoot":"","swcTraceProfiling":false,"forceSwcTransforms":false,"largePageDataBytes":128000,"enableUndici":false,"adjustFontFallbacks":false,"adjustFontFallbacksWithSizeAdjust":false,"trustHostHeader":false},"configFileName":"next.config.js"},
  })
  handler = nextServer.getRequestHandler()

  console.log(
    'Listening on port',
    currentPort,
    'url: http://localhost:' + currentPort
  )
})
```

And as you see it starts a http server not a https. Also this is why the `console.log("lksdfjls");` in your own server.js will not get executed.

What I would suggest is to leave node as it is, running on http://localhost:3000 and set up a reverse proxy that would forward incoming requests to this node backend that is accessible only from the reverse proxy. And of course reverse proxy would handle TLS termination. A docker compose setup would be more convenient for this so you could put the reverse proxy container (nginx for example) in the compose project too and map a directory from the docker host where your cert files are stored into the reverse proxy container at runtime - **DO NOT BAKE CERTS OR ANY OTHER SECRETS INTO ANY IMAGE**, not even if it is an internally used image only because it could leak out accidentally any time.

Also you could just manually run the two container with `docker run` but compose would make life easier it has a lot of capabilities for example you could scale compose services up and down so your backend service would run not in one but many containers. But if this would be a high load and/or business critical production stuff then you are better off with a better (real) container orchestrator like kubernetes, docker swarm, nomad etc but today as I see it the de facto container orchestrator is kubernetes.